# In ffmpeg truehd encoder, can you mark L and R as LT and RT (Dolby Surround)

Tags: ffmpeg, matroska, lossless, dolby-pro-logic

When encoding a stereo audio stream with the ffmpeg ac3 encoder, you can specify that the L/R channels are Dolby-Surround (Pro-Logic) LT/RT channels, using the `-dsur_mode 2` flag.

Is there a way to do this when encoding as TrueHD in a Matroska container? (using `-acodec truehd -strict -2`)